# Drupal: Customize blog post "submission" area?

Tags: php, drupal

I created my own `node-blog.tpl.php` - I'm looking to modify this code:

```
<?php if ( $submitted ):?>
<span class="submitted"><?php echo $submitted;?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need to re-arrange the structure of the contents of the `$submitted` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the [Submitted By](https://www.drupal.org/project/submitted_by) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ...  lets you control the format of the "Submitted by" information on your content per content type. It adds a fieldset to your node edit form called Appearance that lets you put in a tokenized pattern for the text you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_node_submitted/6

 You can retheme it in template.php or remove print $submitted and print manually username and created as you want...